# Derivative of multivariate Gaussian PDF with respect to covariance

Tags: statistics, derivatives, partial-derivative

While trying to derive the M-step of the EM-algorithm for a mixture of Gaussians, I came across this derivative, which I have no idea how to deal with:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma_k}} \left ( (2\pi)^{-d/2}|\mathbf{\Sigma_k}|^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mathbf{\mu_k})^T\mathbf{\Sigma_k}^{-1}(x-\mathbf{\mu_k})}\right )
$$

Basically, this the derivative of the multivariate Gaussian PDF with respect to the covariance matrix. My matrix calculus is not very good - how do I approach this?

I've computed the derivative of the *logarithm* of this PDF before and that was a bit easier because the $|\mathbf{\Sigma_k}|$ and $\mathbf{\Sigma_k}^{-1}$ were in two separate terms that were added/subtracted. But here they are in two terms that are multiplied together.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer and I'm posting it for posterity. I mentioned in the question that computing the derivative of the *logarithm* of the PDF was easier. It turns out that this can be used to compute the derivative of the PDF itself:

$$
\frac{\partial \ln (f)}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}_k} = \frac{1}{f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}_k}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}_k} = f \cdot\frac{\partial \ln (f)}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}_k}
$$

Also, it turns out that taking the derivative of the PDF with respect to $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}$ is easier and leads to the same answer.